# converting basic HTML to RML (Reportlab Markup Language)

Tags: python, reportlab

Is there any Python library or some sample code which demonstrates how to convert basic HTML into RML (Reportlab Markup Language www.reportlab.org)? I can think of using a regular HTML parser and adding some home grown code to generate the RML, but I guess there will be a lot of cases to handle in such a conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have much trouble doing this.  Aside from some differences in element names, it's pretty straightforward:  just ignore any HTML elements that can't be easily converted/you don't care about converting to RML and do the rest.  I'm sure the ReportLab folks would be glad if you contributed even a basic HTML to RML parser to the project.

Comment: Thanx. I will try to come up with something.

Answer (score 0):

simple converter ( [Convert HTML to RML](http://linuxminded.xs4all.nl/dpc/html2rml/)

Comment: Question is about python, not perl